# How can i let the user work on an excel sheet while a message box is displayed on top?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim strMsg As String

strMsg = "Preperation completed. SAP Logon will open in 5 seconds! Please follow the instructions below to retrieve the ART file from SAP" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strMsg = strMsg & "1. Log into SAP using your Username and ID" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strMsg = strMsg & "2. Launch the 'ZMM_ART' Report" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strMsg = strMsg & "3. Insert the data from the 'DATA FOR SAP' Sheet to the relevent fields" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strMsg = strMsg & "4. Insert '0001' as the Location ID" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strMsg = strMsg & "5. Run the Report" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strMsg = strMsg & "6. Save the report as 'ART.xls' to the 'REQUIRED FILES' Folder in your Desktop" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
strMsg = strMsg & "7. Click OK and close this message box" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation + vbSystemModal, "Instructions"
```

I need to display the above message box at some point of a macro. But i need the user to be able to work on the excel sheet while having the said message box on top. (ie: Copy data from the aforementioned 'DATA FOR SAP' Sheet and paste it in SAP) How do you suggest i should do that?

PS: Anyone wondering why, i don't have RFC authorization so this is what i'm reduced to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.

> vbSystemModal - *System modal; all applications are **suspended** until the user responds to the message box*.

Comment: :/ Too bad. Is there any other Style i can use to achieve this?

Comment: If you were using C/C++/C#, I'd recommend an independent dialog that forced itself to be the top window while allowing users to interact with second tier windows. You might try that with a user form in VBA.

Comment: @NickRazzleflamm you can get something similar msgbox, use userform instead of messagebox with `vbModeless`, should be something like this: `UserForm1.Show False`

Comment: user10735198 and @Vasily Thank you! I'll try a form and update on the success. :)

Comment: @NickRazzleflamm also for automation of the SAP interaction you can use `SAPGUI Scripting`, here examples https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sap+gui+scripting+excel

Comment: @Vasily I looked into GUI Scripting, i have it enabled in the Accessibility and Scripting Menu in the Options, but it's grayed out in the "Customize Local Layout" tab. I guess that mean the GUI Scripting API is disabled on the server for me?

Comment: @NickRazzleflamm yes, unfortunately, but not only for you, this feature can be enabled/disabled for all users of SAP instance only

Comment: @Vasily Yes. I contacted my IT department on getting the necessary permissions for it. They said the same thing. I decided to prompt for the user to run the report manually and save it to a set location and read the saved file to run the rest of the code. Really inconvenient, but i have no other option. Thanks for your help. :)